# Dafny precondition 0 <= size < capacity might not hold

Tags: arrays, insert, dafny, preconditions

I am new in Dafny and I try to figure out why this doesn't work. What I want to do is to insert 2 values in my arrays, `priorities`, respectively `values`.
I have the following code:

```
class Queue<V> {
    var size: int;
    ghost var capacity: int;
    var priorities: array<int>;
    var values: array<V>;

    predicate Valid()
    reads this
    {
        0 <= size <= capacity &&
        capacity == priorities.Length &&
        capacity == values.Length
    }

    constructor(aCapacity: int, defaultValue: V)
    requires aCapacity >= 0
    ensures Valid()
    {
        size := 0;
        values := new V[aCapacity](i => defaultValue);
        priorities := new int[aCapacity];
        capacity := aCapacity;
    }

    method insertValues(priority: int, value: V)
    modifies this.values, this.priorities, this
    requires Valid()
    requires 0 <= size < capacity  // here is the problem
    ensures Valid()
    ensures capacity == values.Length && capacity == priorities.Length
    {
        this.values[size] := value;
        this.priorities[size] := priority;
        size := size + 1;
    }
}

method Main() {
    var queue := new Queue<int>(10, 0);
    queue.insertValues(1, 10);
    queue.insertValues(2, 11);
}
```

But when I try to tests my method `insertValues` in Main it says that

```
call may violate context's modifies clause
A precondition for this call might not hold.
```

and the precondition is `0 <= size < capacity`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Dafny analyzes each method in isolation, using only the specifications of the other methods. See the [Dafny FAQ](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#my-program-is-correct-but-dafny-says-there-is-a-problem-what-gives) for more information.

You need to add more postconditions to guarantee that certain things aren't changed by `insertValues`, and you need to also add more postconditions to the constructor so that callers know the initial state. Here is a version that verifies:

```
class Queue<V> {
    var size: int;
    ghost var capacity: int;
    var priorities: array<int>;
    var values: array<V>;

    predicate Valid()
    reads this
    {
        0 <= size <= capacity &&
        capacity == priorities.Length &&
        capacity == values.Length
    }

    constructor(aCapacity: int, defaultValue: V)
    requires aCapacity >= 0
    ensures Valid()
    ensures fresh(priorities) && fresh(values)
    ensures size == 0 && capacity == aCapacity
    {
        size := 0;
        values := new V[aCapacity](i => defaultValue);
        priorities := new int[aCapacity];
        capacity := aCapacity;
    }

    method insertValues(priority: int, value: V)
    modifies this.values, this.priorities, this
    requires Valid()
    requires 0 <= size < capacity  // here is the problem
    ensures Valid()
    ensures capacity == old(capacity) && size == old(size) + 1 && values == old(values) && priorities == old(priorities)
    {
        this.values[size] := value;
        this.priorities[size] := priority;
        size := size + 1;
    }
}

method Main() {
    var queue := new Queue<int>(10, 0);
    queue.insertValues(1, 10);
    queue.insertValues(2, 11);
}
```